# capture strings that cannot be converted to date in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I want to create an `if` statement if the string cannot be converted to date, like the one below:

```
as.Date("2010-00-01")
```

But running the line above just keep giving the error output below:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Which I cannot use it for `if` statement, how can I use a `if` statement if the string cannot be converted to date? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide the `format` arg so it won't be ambiguous. Bad dates are then always turned into `NA`.

```
d <- as.Date("2010-01-31", format="%Y-%m-%d") # OK
is.na(d) # FALSE

d <- as.Date("2010-00-31", format="%Y-%m-%d") # NA
is.na(d) # TRUE
```

Comment: I prefer Tommy's answer, as it is done without creating new function, but learning `tryCatch` from kohske is also good.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick definition:

```
isDatable <- function(x) tryCatch(as.Date(x), error = function(e) FALSE)
```

Then,

```
> isDatable("2012-00-01")
[1] FALSE
> isDatable("2012-01-01")
[1] "2012-01-01"
```

so you can use with `if`:

```
if (!isDatable("2012-00-01")) {
    # something 
}
```